# Cigarette smoking vs Smoking cigarettes

Tags: difference, gerunds

> Cigarette smoking is harmful to our health.
>   Smoking cigarettes is harmful for our health.
>
> Playing football is beneficial to our health.
>   Football playing is beneficial to our health.

Are all the sentences given above correct?
If they are not, please explain!

Comment: Grammatically, yes. Playing football is about as harmful as smoking, though.

Comment: Is "football playing" idiomatic?

Comment: Certainly, as a check of a couple of corpora shows. *Football playing* is far less common that *playing football*, but the latter cannot replace the former as a modifier: "My **football playing** days are over.") and in instances like this one I found: "if momentum is going to explain successful **football playing**...."

Answer (score 1):

Smoking can be a verb or a noun. It is the *action* of smoking (eg "he is smoking a cigarette") and also the *name* of the habit of smoking tobacco (eg "the effect of smoking on health").

- "Smoking cigarettes" is a *verb* followed by a *noun*.
- "Cigarette-smoking" is a *compound verb*.

So, they are different, even though they mean the same. "Smoking" as a verb alone is very non-specific as it could refer to the smoking of other substances, or even other methods of delivering tobacco, not just cigarettes. So you *need* both ways because you'll often need to clarify it.

"Football" doesn't need any the same kind of clarification. It is the name of a game, and you play games. So you can say "playing football" to denote that you are participating in it (as opposed to passively watching it) but "football-playing" is not idiomatic as it is somewhat unnecessary.

Comment: Cigarette smoking is not a compound verb. Smoking is a noun modified by the noun cigarette.

Comment: Smoking is a verb, @Hunter.

Comment: @Corsaka It's also a noun. It is the *name* of the habit of smoking tobacco. Google "smoking definition" and see what comes up. ;)

Comment: @Hunter Yes it is, just like "air-conditioning" or "sound-proofing".

Comment: It is not a verb. It is clearly a noun modified by another noun. You cannot modify a verb with a noun. Look at the sentence carefully. Cigarette smoking is separated. It is the same as "Excessive smoking". It has no verbal feature. We modify a verb with an adverb and a noun with an adjective or another noun.

Comment: @Corsaka when you say "smoking cigarette" it is clearly a verb, but when you say "cigarette smoking" it is undoubtedly a noun.

Comment: The contention here arises from the confusion of form (i.e., a word’s lexical properties) and function (i.e., how the word operates within the structure of a sentence). *Smoking*  is a verb: it’s the present participle of the verb *to smoke*. As a verb in a clause, it can take a *subject* and an **object** (I saw *him* smoking **a cigar**.) Nouns can’t do that. On the other hand, *smoking* cannot be pluralized the way nouns can: smoking two cigars doesn’t give rise to *smokings*. (con't->)

Comment: (<-con't)  That’s form. When we get to function, we find that *smoking* can take the same roles as nouns — subject (“**Smoking** is bad for you.”), object (“I quit **smoking**.”), and attributive (“**Smoking jacket**”). This  isn’t to say that present participles can’t become nouns. When they do, they take noun forms, e.g, *saying* meaning aphorism. The plural *sayings* is now possible. When this happens, the noun often has a specialized meaning. A saying is just not anything someone says.

Comment: -ing forms are notoriously difficult to classify, and I don't think it is as simple as asking whether it can be pluralized. In "All that cigarette smoking is repulsive!", *smoking* appears to be the head of a noun phrase, so it would make sense to call it a noun (gerund) there. ("All that smoking cigarettes is repulsive." is less natural, and probably only works if *smoking-cigarettes* is interpreted as a quoted phrase.)